# Is there any reason to do server side logic in JSP instead of calling methods from external classes?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a web app running in jetty and in the JSP I e.g insert some values to my DB the following way:

```
 <% 
if(request.getParameter("id") != null && request.getParameter("value") != null){
int poiId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

int value = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("value")); 

FirstExample.insertReading(value, id);   // here I 
}
%>
```

Is there a reason why I should not do method calling like this? I could have performed this useing JTSL i think its called?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Servlet`, in MVC model `JSP` is mainly used as view. No need to deal with big logic in `JSP`.

Comment: Exactly. Each JSP translates to Servlet implementation by the server, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to do it at all. Actually, put the logic/actions in JSP is a bad practice. Separate logic out of JSP is much better design. Same logic can be used by many JSPs or other implementations.

Comment: wow that is nice. I just started using java server and feel so much power with it compared to PHP